# Como convertir formato de hora en day.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

Necesito convertir el siguiente formato de hora militar a 12 horas (Meridiana o Standart) con day.js.

```
let horas = ["15:00:00", "09:30:00"];
console.log(horas);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Incluye un video, que también recomiendo ver o escuchar el contenido al menos :)

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación en estos link:
https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format#list-of-localized-formats
https://zetcode.com/javascript/dayjs/

Debería de ser así:

```
dayjs.extend(LocalizedFormat);
dayjs().format('L LT');
```

o así:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

let now = dayjs();

console.log("ISO")
console.log(now.format());

console.log("\nTime")
console.log(now.format("HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(now.format("h:mm:ss a"));

console.log("\nDate")
console.log(now.format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY"));
console.log(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

en teoría el formato que debes aplicar es: "h:mm:ss a"
Otra forma de convertirlo sin `day.js` seria implementar el siguiente método (Adaptándolo a tu necesidad):

Documentación: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206656/4717133

```
var time = "16:30:00"; // your input

time = time.split(':'); // convert to array

// fetch
var hours = Number(time[0]);
var minutes = Number(time[1]);
var seconds = Number(time[2]);

// calculate
var timeValue;

if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
  timeValue= "" + hours;
} else if (hours > 12) {
  timeValue= "" + (hours - 12);
} else if (hours == 0) {
  timeValue= "12";
}
 
timeValue += (minutes < 10) ? ":0" + minutes : ":" + minutes;  // get minutes
timeValue += (seconds < 10) ? ":0" + seconds : ":" + seconds;  // get seconds
timeValue += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";  // get AM/PM

// show
alert(timeValue);
console.log(timeValue);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve buscando en todas partes de la documentación en day.js que se pudiera hacer esto pero no, al final implementaré la función yo mismo, mil gracias

Comment: @JhonatanFlorez no entiendo tu comentario … si vez en mi respuesta agrego los link de la  documentación en donde esta la solución usando `day.js`, y te acabo de pasar la un método sin librería que hace la conversión, te sirven o no te sirven mi respuesta??? por que harías otra cosa?